# How to choose database table according to input type=radio tag in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql database, one for student and one for teacher. Both tables have the same columns.

The code below inserts data only to the teacher's table. If user selects teacher's radio button, then the sign up data should be stored in teacher's table. If the user selects student's radio, then the sign up data should be stored in student's table.

**Radio button don't work to choose database table it only insert data in mysql student table either I select teacher radio button**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37VMG.jpg)

```
String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
if (gender != null) {
    String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
    // replace dots with your values
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
    st.executeUpdate(query);
} // Here is also error but it insert data in table of only student.
```

**PROBLEM IS ALSO HERE**

`st.executeUpdate(query);`

**index.jsp**

```
<form  method="GET " action="statement2.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student
   <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
   <input type="button" onclick="location.href='reg.jsp';" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

**statement2.jsp**

```
<%
   String name=request.getParameter("first");
   String abc=request.getParameter("last");
   String cde=request.getParameter("user");
   String pass=request.getParameter("password");
   String confpass=request.getParameter("confirmpass");
   String emails=request.getParameter("email");
   String months=request.getParameter("month");
   String day=request.getParameter("day");
   String year=request.getParameter("year");

   String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
   if (gender != null) {
   String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
// replace dots with your values
   String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
  st.executeUpdate(query);}     // problem is here

 %>
```

---

**reg.jsp**

```
<form  method="GET" action="statement2.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
    <h1> Sign up </h1> 
    <p> 
    <label for="firstnamesignup" class="fname" data-icon="u">First Name:</label>
    <input id="firstnamesignup" name="first" required="required" type="text" placeholder="First" />
    </p>
    <p> 
     <label for="lastnamesignup" class="lname" data-icon="u">Last Name:</label>
     <input id="lastnamesignup" name="last" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Last" />
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username:</label>
     <input id="usernamesignup" name="user" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password:</label>
     <input id="passwordsignup" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="password" data-icon="p">Confirm Password:</label>
     <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="confirmpass" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" >Email:</label>
     <input id="emailsignup" name="email" required="required" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"/> 
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label>Date of Birth:</label>
     <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="na">Month</option>
     <option value="1">January</option>
     <option value="2">February</option>
     <option value="3">March</option>
     <option value="4">April</option>
     <option value="5">May</option>
     <option value="6">June</option>
     <option value="7">July</option>
     <option value="8">August</option>
     <option value="9">September</option> 
     <option value="10">October</option>
     <option value="11">November</option>
     <option value="12">December</option>
     </select>
     <select name="day" id="day">
     <option value="na">Day</option>
     </select>
     <select name="year" id="year">
     <option value="na">Year</option>
     </select>
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function changeDate(i){
     var e = document.getElementById('day');
     while(e.length>0)
     e.remove(e.length-1);
     var j=-1;
     if(i=="na")
     k=0;
     else if(i==2)
     k=28;
     else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
     k=30;
     else
     k=31;
     while(j++<k){
     var s=document.createElement('option');
     var e=document.getElementById('day');
     if(j==0){
     s.text="Day";
     s.value="na";
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}
     else{
     s.text=j;
     s.value=j;
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}}}
     y = 1998;
     while (y-->1908){
     var s = document.createElement('option');
     var e = document.getElementById('year');
     s.text=y;
     s.value=y;
     try{
     e.add(s,null);}
     catch(ex){
     e.add(s);}}
     </script> 
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label>Gender:</label>
     <select name="Gender">
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
     </select>
     </p>
     <p class="signin button"> 
     <input type="submit" value="Register"/> 
     </p>
 </form>
```

---

**db conn.jsp**

```
       <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
       <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
       <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
       <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
       <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h1>Hello World!</h1>

       <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
       <%
        Connection c1 = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        c1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher","root", "abcde");

        System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
        System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

        st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
             System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
             {
         System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

         }

         if (c1!= null) {
         System. out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
         } else {
         System.out.println("We should never get here.");
         }}
        %>
```

Comment: Are you getting the respective value whichever you select from radio button?

Comment: @mady No, i don't getting value from radio button.How can i get radio button value. i only know to get value by name but radio button have same name

Answer (score 1):

First of all some best practice:

1. Use form method=POST when you want to create/update data on server
2. Use PreparedStatement for INSERT/UPDATE instead of Statement

now, back to your problem with radio button:
The page that sends data to be stored in your table is **reg.jsp** which on submit is calling **statement2.jsp**. You don't have the radio button with name="gender" in **reg.jsp**, in fact is in **index.jsp**.

You have two options:

1. You pass selected value of radio button to reg.jsp; and here you use a hidden field in the form, this way is passed to statement2.jsp
2. You add the radio buttons in reg.jsp.

Comment: How to pass selected value of radio button of index.jsp to reg.jsp and what will be it mysql query to select table from same database?

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="location.href='reg.jsp';" value="Sign Up" /> here you ca replace onclick with a javascript function, i.e. reg(){ window.location = 'reg.jsp' + '?gender=' + SELECTED_VALUE_OF_RADIO_BUTTON;}

in reg.jsp -> <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="<%=request.getParameter("gender")%>"/>

That's all.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
 <input type="button" reg(){ window.location = 'reg.jsp' + '?gender=' + SELECTED_VALUE_OF_RADIO_BUTTON;}" value="Sign Up" /><input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student` my  sign  submit button value sign is remove

Answer (score 0):

First of all for this scenario you dont need multiple tables with same column. Just use one table with the all columns currently have and create an additional `column` with name `user_type`. The `user_type` `column` should have values either `teacher` or `student` depends on the input you are getting from the user end.
Change the query as below

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name
(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender,user_type)
VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"',
'"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"','"+USER_TYPE_SELECTED+"')";
```

Comment: The thing you are talking about to have only a table for both student and teacher data is totally opposite to my question.How can i select a table to insert data on the basic of radio button?

Comment: I suggested a better way to do the scenario. For your question what is the problem with this code .. it should work     `String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";`

Comment: @ vipin cp My problem is to choose database table on the basis of  input field `<input type=radio name ="gender" value="teacher">` </input>  `<input type=radio name ="gender" value="Student">Student</input>` how can i do that?

Comment: @RajpootRajpoot`<input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher` Remove checked in the above code and try. Atleast you can debug what value is coming for gender right?

Comment: i have remove checked from teacher input type but same problem is comming i know im not using radio value parameters in reg.jsp and statement2.jsp that is problem how to use input value in jsp as a getparameter

Comment: `<%=var%>  or ${variable} `

Comment: what will be query for this<%=var%>